# Loop on XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, shred

In my SQL Server table one column has datatype as XML. It contains data as:

```
<P1>
<P2>
<P3 name='[1] name1', value='val1'> </P3>
<P3 name='[2] name2', value='val2'> </P3>
<P3 name='[3] name3', value='val3'> </P3>
</P2>
</p1>
```

I am fetching name1, name2, name3 using query:

```
select top(1)
    col.value('(/P1[1]/P2[1]/P3/@name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as q1,
    col.value('(/P1[1]/P2[1]/P3/@name)[2]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as q2,
    col.value('(/P1[1]/P2[1]/P3/@name)[3]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as q3,

    FROM table
```

**How can I loop on this data to get all the names. Something like:**

```
declare @x=1
while @x<4:
begin
    select top(1)
        col.value('(/P1[1]/P2[1]/P3/@name)[@x]', 'VARCHAR(max)') as q@x
        from table
    set @x=@x+1
end
```

**Also how to loop on the same XML to get all the values?**

Comment: Your XML sample is not well-formed XML. Please edit your post and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of making your XML well-formed. SQL Server *XQuery* `.nodes()` method and `CROSS APPLY` are delivering what you are after.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata)
VALUES
(N'<P1>
    <P2>
        <P3 name="[1] name1" value="val1">
        </P3>
        <P3 name="[2] name2" value="val2">
        </P3>
        <P3 name="[3] name3" value="val3">
        </P3>
    </P2>
</P1>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT tbl.ID
    , c.value('@name','VARCHAR(30)') AS [name]
    , c.value('@value','VARCHAR(30)') AS [value]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xmldata.nodes('/P1/P2/P3') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| ID |   name    | value |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  1 | [1] name1 | val1  |
|  1 | [2] name2 | val2  |
|  1 | [3] name3 | val3  |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: How will I get all the names and values (in the same order) if I have XML like:  <P1>
    <P2>
    <P3 name='[1] name1', value='val1'> </P3>
    <P4 name='[1] name2', value='val2'> </P4>
    <P3 name='[2] name3', value='val3'> </P3>
    <P5 name='[1] name4', value='val4'> </P5>
    <P3 name='[3] name5', value='val5'> </P3>
    </P2>
    </p1>